# How to allow root login server and disallow website users connection in centos 7 maintenance period?

Tags: maintenance, systemctl, runlevel

My clound VPS server is `centos 7.4`,I run `apache`,`mariadb` in this server.
Now,I want to migrate from `mariadb` to `mysql`.
During maintenance, server need `no user disturb`.
In centos 7, has no `run level 1`,then I read [this post](https://www.webhostinghero.com/blog/centos-safe-mode-for-maintenance/) and tried `systemctl rescue`,the result is I cannot login my server any more.
I guess `systemctl rescue` close any connection even I am root.
Then, In maintenance period,How to allow root login server and disallow website users connection?

Comment: there is no supported mariadb -> mysql migration. You'll need to do a mysqldump of the database(s) and restore it into an install mysql. I suspect just disabling apache will be sufficient to preform this migration without interruption.

Comment: Will `disabling apache` cause `data inconsistency`?

Comment: No stopping the apache service will prevent database updates from the web. It won't cause data inconsistency. Don't forget to copy the database users and grants. BTW, what mariadb feature is missing for you to choose this migration?

Comment: @danblack, mariadb has a messy official website.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I wish you well in your migration. Be careful, the isolation question you asked is the easiest part of the migration. Take a backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stopping the apache service will enable a database migration without web traffic changing the database:

```
systemctl stop apache.service
```

Start service after completing the migration:

```
systemctl start apache.service
```